# Cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'

Tags: python

When I run project on my local machine gives this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections_*init*_.py)

any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

because there is no object called `Mapping` in `collections`
check the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

this object exists in a different module To import that
`from _collections_abc import Mapping`

Answer (score -1):

My `C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py` *from* section didn't seem to have the required entries.

To resolve this, I added the following to that file:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from collections.abc import Sequence
```

Additionally my project .py file still had the legacy code line `import collections` which I replaced with the new code line `from collections.abc import Mapping`